# How to get value from mat checkbox . The problem I am facing is , when i check one box , all other boxes are getting checked

Tags: html, angular

This is the HTML PART WHICH IS IMPLEMENTED which takes in the checked value and passes it to the angular component and the design for your information is for quiz component and answers,.value represents the options {1,2,3,4}.

So I want to take in the value from the checkbox and whether the user has pressed or not , if pressed then the particular checkbox will be taken and the particular checkbox value can be compared and then user can be notified whether his selected option is right or wrong.

Problem:

So currently I was working on getting checked value meaning that the checkbox is clicked and the value is passed , so on the output /website , when I pressed /checked one option , others also were checked.

Suggestions since new in Angular:
So where is the code cliche here. Also in the comments any help on how to design a quiz component where in :

1: User presses one checkbox/button , angular takes in a value and stores it until user presses the submit button.

2: User presses the submit button , he sees red which means selected was wrong and the green one is right
3: alternatively , he selected the correct one before submitting and he sees only the corrected one.

```html
    <section class='question-section'> 
             <ol>
               <li *ngFor='let answers of options'>
                <mat-checkbox class="option-style-margin" [checked]="checked"  (change)="changed($event)">
                {{answers.value}}
                </mat-checkbox>
               </li>
               </ol>
              </section>
```

```js
                class answerDataStructure{
                  check:boolean;
                  value:string;
                  expanded:boolean;
                  constructor(answers){
                    this.value=answers;
                    this.check=false;
                   }
                }
                options:answerDataStructure[]=[];
                  checked:boolean=false;
                changed(event:any){
                this.checked=event.checked //This is the thing I have done 
                    }
```

Comment: Also guys open to any suggestions on how to design such quiz components.    So let us say we  have four options with checkbox. When user selcts one checkbox , that corresponding checkbox and the option should be sent. Now when user selects submit , he gets to know whether he is right or wrong.

Comment: did you implemented anything before ?

Answer (score 0):

You have your `<mat-checkbox>` inside an `ngFor` and the flag you are using to check a box is using the `checked` field instead of your `answers.check`.

This change will check only the single option that you are looking for. I suggest using a RadioButton instead of Checkbox for most (or all questions) if there is only one correct answer.

To implement submit functionality you would then adjust your `(change)` event to to populate the current choice(s). I will assume you can only have one correct answer. You will also need some sort of answer key will the correct answers for each question.

```
currentChoices: number[] = [];
answerKey: number[] = [
   1,
   3,
   4,
   // etc
];



changed(event: any, question: number, choice: number) {
    console.log(this.currentChoices);
    if (event.checked) {
      // user selected answer
      this.currentChoices[question] = choice;
    } else {
      // user unselected answer
      this.currentChoices[question] = -1;
    }
}
```

Now a submit button would need to call a function like this:

```
submitAnswer(question: number) {
    console.log(this.currentChoices[0]);
    if (this.currentChoices[question] == undefined || this.currentChoices[question] == -1) {
      console.log('No answer was selected!');
    } else if (this.answerKey[question] === this.currentChoices[question]) {
      console.log('Correct!');
    } else {
      console.log('Incorrect!');
    }
}
```

Lastly, the html. Here I'm hardcoding the first question (index 0). This whole section+button should be wrapped in an `ngFor` over all your questions

```
<section class='question-section'> 
  <ol>
    <li *ngFor='let answers of options; let j=index'>
     <mat-checkbox class="option-style-margin" [checked]="answers.check"  (change)="changed($event, 0, j)">
     {{answers.value}}
     </mat-checkbox>
    </li>
    </ol>
   </section>
<button (click)="submitAnswer(0)">submit</button>
```

Also keep in mind that this doesn't stop you from selecting multiple answers. We will only keep the last checked option, that's why I suggest radio buttons. Also unchecked an option will result in -1 and we aren't setting the option back to any others that are selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the suggestions will make use of them. Your explanation was on point , helps me a lot. Thanks again

Comment: How would you implement this in mat-radio button

Comment: The examples should help you: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples

MatRadioButton also has the `(change)` property so it shouldnt be much difference

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help! Means a lot